# SQL Case Statement or Different Method?

Tags: sql

I will be using my output to place into an Excel pivot table. The data is dealing with credit accounts that have either charged off or not.

EDIT: If chargeoffs is checked in the pivot table I want the totalaccounts column to be a count of total accounts regardless of the chargeoffdate value. If chargeoffs is left unchecked I want totalaccounts to be a count of all accounts when chargeoffdate is NULL.

Here is my SQL syntax so far:

```
SELECT  
c.brand,
CASE WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NULL THEN 'No Chargeoffs'
 -- Below here should not be only chargeoffs, it should be chargeoffs + the column above ^^^
 WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Chargeoffs'
 ELSE 'Unknown' END AS chargeoffs,

COUNT(*) AS totalaccounts

FROM accounts
GROUP BY brand, chargeoffs
```

You can see the comment in my SQL to understand what I am going for, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

I tried:

```
CASE WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NULL THEN 'No Chargeoffs'
 -- Below here should not be only chargeoffs, it should be chargeoffs + the column above ^^^
 WHEN (a.chargeoffdate IS NOT NULL OR a.chargeoffdate IS NULL) THEN 'Chargeoffs Included'
 ELSE 'Unknown' END AS chargeoffs
```

But got the same results as the top query for some reason. Thanks.

ANOTHER EDIT: OUTPUT DESIRED

```
BRAND 1 | WITH CHARGEOFFS       | COUNT(TOTALACCOUNTS)
BRAND 1 | WITHOUT CHARGEOFFS    | COUNT(TOTALACCOUNTS)
BRAND 2 | WITH CHARGEOFFS       | COUNT(TOTALACCOUNTS)
BRAND 2 | WITHOUT CHARGEOFFS    | COUNT(TOTALACCOUNTS)
```

Comment: Are chargeoff and and nonchargeoffs columns on your table, or values in a column in your table?

Comment: This seems like an odd condition: `a.chargeoffdate IS NOT NULL OR a.chargeoffdate IS NULL`  are you aware that it will always evaluate true?

Comment: chargeoffdate is the column. if it is null they have not charged off otherwise they have. chargeoffs is just the alias and thats how I am grouping the case statement so it can be used in a pivot table

Comment: @ abe, I want it to always be true because I want to either include all values, or include all values minus accounts that have charged off and then group it like that

Comment: Why not just use an else statement?  As far as I can tell your current else is unreachable

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

Chargeoffs = Count of all accounts whether chargeoffdate is null or not

No Chargeoffs = Count of all accounts where chargeoffdate is null (they haven't charged off)

```
SELECT
    brand,
    count(*) as "Chargeoffs",
    sum(CASE WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'No Chargeoffs'
FROM accounts
GROUP BY brand
```

UPDATE: I'm tired, I obtained this long SQL, wich is near what you want:

```
SELECT brand,
       tp,
       CASE WHEN TP = 1 then sum(cnt) END as 'No Chargeoffs', 
       sum(cnt) as "Chargeoffs"
FROM(
    SELECT
        brand,
        CASE WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as tp
        count(*) as cnt
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY brand,  CASE WHEN a.chargeoffdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
GROUP BY brand, tp
```

Comment: Well all my other columns are counts so say I count(*), I want my output to be: Chargeoffs = Count of all accounts whether chargeoffdate is null or not and No Chargeoffs = Count of all accounts where chargeoffdate is null (they haven't charged off)

Comment: ok, please update your post, with entire sql, or some counts, to make us understand

Comment: I just edited my question to make it more understandable, let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: Couple things to say about this edit. It gets what I am asking for, but I need it to be grouped so that I can use it in a pivot table as a checkbox. Is this even possible? Also, I think your second column would need to be a SUM rather than COUNT

Comment: Yes I do. Every other column is a count or sum so it will be 4 total lines. 2 brands and 2 chargeoffs or not for each.

Brand 1 | Chargeoffs
Brand 1 | No Chargeoffs
Brand 2 | Chargeoffs
Brand 2 | No Chargeoffs

Answer (score 0):

That was kind of stupid and my solution was easy. I just left it how I had it and the pivot table added them together for me.

I found this out after I had created 2 separate queries and did some data manipulation with SAS to get what I wanted. Ouch.